# script tag without preceding slash is going to root

Tags: html

This problem should be so simple that I'm embarrased to ask, but I'm not understanding what it is happening.

I have a very very simple html file, which references only one javascript file through an script tag. When this html file is served from the root of the domain it works perfectly. However, when it is served from a subpath it does not work.

The reason is because the browser is asking for the script tag to the root of the domain, which is obviously wrong.

The html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>Licenses manager</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            If you're seeing this message, that means <strong>JavaScript has been disabled on your browser</strong>
            , please <strong>enable JS</strong>
            to make this app work.
        </noscript>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.82f885da14b87d36c0f1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the script tag does not have any preceding slash `/`, so it should be interpreted as relative to the current domain. However, if I inspect the network tab I can see that the browser is asking to the root of the domain `https://example.com/main.82f885...js`

Why does this happen?

** Edit for clarify**

I'm sorry about not explicitly saying that both files are at the same level. The sub path is being added by a load balancer. Files are like this on the public folder:

|- index.html
   |- main.82f885da14b87d36c0f1.js

And the load balancer has a rule to send request to `/licenses` to an specific server. So, if the browsers asks for `http://example.com/licenses/main.js` then the correct file is served. However, instead of keeping the requests under the same sub-path, the browser is asking to the root of the domain.

Comment: this happened to me also don't know the reason, I was loading a list of script urls I get from the server during the app boot up, there is a build file which happened to be same origin and it is missing `/` at the beginning looks like this `dist/component.bundle.js` . Now when the users are reloading from a certain route like `my.app.com/tab` then the script is trying to load from `my.app.com/tab/dist/component.bundle.js` , instead of `my.app.com/dist/component.bundle.js` and script is failing. Adding a `/` does fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for references to all assets. Where you're mistaken is that a relative path (no leading /) is that it is not relative to the root domain. It is relative to the current URL of the page you are on. Examples:

**One Folder Deep**

`http://domain/first/page.html`

**Correct Relative Path:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../main.82f885da14b87d36c0f1.js"></script>
```

**Correct Absolute Path (Also Could Be Considered Relative to Domain):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.82f885da14b87d36c0f1.js"></script>
```

**Translated Absolute Path For Both Of the Above:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain/main.82f885da14b87d36c0f1.js"></script>
```

**Two Folders Deep**

`http://domain/first/second/page.html`

**Correct Relative Path:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../main.82f885da14b87d36c0f1.js"></script>
```

**Correct Absolute Path (Also Could Be Considered Relative to Domain):**

**Translated Absolute Path For Both Of the Above:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain/main.82f885da14b87d36c0f1.js"></script>
```

Comment: What you describe is exactly the opposite of what I want. I have edited my question to clarify this. I want the browser to ask for the js file at the same level/subfolder the html file is.

Comment: do an inline javascript on the page that outputs your window.location.href. You also need to look at the headers that are coming through on the actual HTML page. I would wager your load balancer is providing a translation, redirect or transformation (x-header), OR at worse, an iframe wrapper (like a stealth redirect).